# Why do I have to re-declare overridden functions in derived classes in c++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, abstract, pure-virtual

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Iinterface
{
  virtual void abstractFunction()=0;
};

class Derived : public Iinterface
{
  void abstractFunction(); // Do I need this line?
};

Derived::abstractFunction()
{
  // implementation here
}
```

If I don't add the line in question, I get compile error which says `abstractFunction` is not declared in `Derived`. I'm using VS 2008.
I'm not sure why I need this particular line *(do not confuse this with the function definition which is provided outside class declaration)*, as long as I'm inheriting from `Iinterface` it should be obvious I have `abstractFunction` declared. Is that a problem with visual studio or is it enforced by c++ standards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the declaration of pure-virtual base functions were implied in all derived classes, then you could never have a derived class that remains abstract with respect to a pure-virtual base function. Instead, all derived classes would produce linker errors. That would be extremely counter-intuitive and confusing, and it would make the language less expressive.

Moreover, it wouldn't even make sense: The question whether the derived class is abstract or not must be known *everywhere* at compile-time. The implementation of the overrider is typically only provided in one single translation unit, so it would be impossible to communicate the fact that you actually mean for the function to be overridden to the rest of the program.

Comment: you've summed it up much better :)

Comment: I agree, this is probably more understandable than my rambling answer, +1.

Comment: Whether the derived class is abstract or not could be known with an explicit "abstract" keyword which C++ lacks.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Yes**: If you want to create an object of the `class Derived`
2. **No**: If you want to keep the `class Derived` also *abstract*
3. **No**: If there is an intermediate class which has already overridden the function
   e.g. between `Iinterface` and `Derived` there is a `class Intermediate` which has overridden `abstractFunction()`; so now it's optional for `class Derived` to override the same

**Edit**: With the changed question title,

> Why do I have to re-declare overridden functions in derived classes in
>   c++?

That's because C++ compiler grammar demands that every member function of the `class` (or `namespace` or file) must be declared inside the `class` (or `namespace` or file) body. Be it `virtual` or normal function.
There is **no** good reason for breaking that consistency just for `virtual` functions.

Comment: I think the OP is aware of the mechanics of overriding a pure-virtual base function. She wants to know why the *declaration* is necessary in the derived class.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you, that's what I exactly meant.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it seems that the title of the question has been edited just now. I will modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A function that ends in an `=0` is called a `deleted function`, this is useful when you don't want objects that use certain constructors (such as `unique_ptr` which has a deleted copy ctor).

If a `virtual` function is deleted then by standard the class becomes an abstract type.  Because in most cases the prototype of a class and the class's function bodies are in separate files, this means that unless you explicitly outline in the prototype that you're overriding the deleted virtual function then you're NOT overriding the deleted virtual function.  The compiler isn't supposed to just simply infer that you meant to put the function in there once it sees the implementation in a completely different file.

Remember that the prototype/implementation idea isn't the only way to write code, you can also put the implementation right in the class (which can be done if the code is small enough and you want to inline the function.)  And to do that you need to again, explicitly override the deleted virtual function.  So because you need to override it anyway, it makes perfect sense that you need to explicitly override it in the prototype.  The function is still deleted otherwise.

For a concrete example: let's say you have a List.hpp, List.cpp and main.cpp

In List.hpp you have an abstract class and a regular class that inherits from the abstract class.  In main you `#include "List.hpp"` and not List.cpp, right?  So the compiler has NO IDEA what's in that file (until it tries to compile it.)  If you don't have the deleted virtual function overridden then the compiler thinks that you're simply trying to instantiate an abstract class and throws an error.

On the other hand, if you're compiling List.cpp, then the compiler will also throw an error, this time complaining that the function you're trying to write has not actually been defined.  Because `Base::deletedFunction()` is different from `Derived::deletedFunction()`.

Comment: Thank you. Is this a compiler limitation or c++ limitation?

Comment: C++ limitation.  Though I would hesitate to call it a limitation.  It's just simply that you have to be explicit about it.  Which helps you in the long run, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the whole point of a pure virtual function is to enforce that you override it in derived class; this declaration has to be explicit in c++

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I **am** overriding it, I just don't understand why I need to rewrite function's prototype within class declaration. Why won't VS infer that itself?

Comment: VS thinks u forgot about that metod :)

Comment: Because class definition drives object hierarchy design, if you will; as immillind explained above, your choice of whether to include the override declaration or not tells compiler whether corresponding method code should be there or not.